# locate returns no results on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

When I search for something simple such as `locate php.ini` or `locate my.cnf` I get no results.

This works as expected on one of my Ubuntu 14.04 boxes but not on the other. Do I need to change an indexing setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into your /etc/updatedb.conf and check that the filenames that you are searching for or the directory locations are not in the PRUNE settings.

Also, if the files are fairly new, try the following command:

```
updatedb
```

Make sure that you are running as root.

Comment: Got this error: `updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'`

Comment: You have to run as root. I'll add this to my answer.